# dialogflow returns "__system_counters__" context output

Tags: output, dialogflow-es

I have a 'help' intent with 3 or so training utterances that is not matching correctly to the phrase "I think I need some help" in one agent, but matching fine in another agent with an identical set of intents and training utts.  In the first agent, Dialogflow is returning "Default Followup", with an output context of `__system_counters__`.  Why is this happening?  I can skirt the problem by adding "I think I need some help" as an additional training utt, but I'm concerned this is just sweeping the problem under the rug.  What does the `__system_counters__` output context mean?

Comment: hi, did you ever resolve this? having the same issue currently. Thanks!

Comment: No. Someone from Google recommended I file an issue, which I did.  But I've gotten no other response.  I think you can vote up the issue and help boost its priority, if you'd like: https://issuetracker.google.com/148242362

Comment: I will, thanks! Also -- did you notice this gave you any problems adding new intents to your project? Since I've been noticing this bug, new intents are also not firing, despite using verbatim training text (might be a chicken and egg though as I've been looking at context more carefully since!).

Comment: I haven't been adding additional intents, sorry.

Comment: An oldie, but did you ever find out what caused this @Jan ? Same issue here been trying to get this fixed for days

Comment: Google tech support told us to just ignore it, that it wasn't important nor relevant.